# Which device file receives keys which I inject on Android?

Tags: android, c, linux

I managed to inject multitouch events on my LG device programmatically ( C code ) injecting them into `/dev/input/event0`. 
But no success with key press injection. I do able to inject keys via `adb shell input keyevent` but i don't see anything happens in `/dev/input/event*` files. Looks like none of them receives nothing. Does anybody know how to localize the file where to inject keys ?
Thanks in advance.

Update:

init device code :

```
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT,  EV_KEY);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_TOUCH);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, KEY_BACK);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, KEY_HOMEPAGE);

for (i = KEY_RESERVED; i <= KEY_UNKNOWN; i++)
    ioctl(obj->m_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, i);

ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT,  EV_ABS);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_X);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_Y);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_MT_POSITION_X);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID);
ioctl (obj->m_fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_MT_PRESSURE);
```

inject touch event code (working)

```
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID, 0       );
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_POSITION_X,  obj->x  );
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y,  obj->y  );
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR, obj->sq );
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_PRESSURE,    obj->pr );
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_SYN, SYN_MT_REPORT, 0);
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_SYN, SYN_MT_REPORT, 0);
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
```

inject key press code where `KEY_RESERVED <= obj->keyCode <=KEY_UNKNOWN` (not working)

```
intSendEvent(obj->m_fd, EV_KEY, obj->keyCode, 1);
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);

intSendEvent(obj->m_fd, EV_KEY, obj->keyCode, 0);
intSendEvent( obj->m_fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
```

send event function

```
void intSendEvent(int fd_kb,int type, int code, int value)
{
        debug("intSendEvent call (%d,%d,%d,%d)", fd_kb, type, code, value);
    struct uinput_event event;
    int len;

    if (fd_kb <= fileno(stderr))
            return;

    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    event.type = type;
    event.code = code;
    event.value = value;

    len = write( fd_kb, &event, sizeof(event) );

    debug("intSendEvent done:%d",len);
}
```

Comment: I believe getevent tells you the source, so if your run that from an adb shell session in one window, and then inject some events with input keyevent in another adb session, you might figure it out *for your particular device*

Comment: This is exactly what i'm doing, and don't see something happens in getevent session when injecting keys.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your injection command that others could try?

Comment: Updated the question, as you asked.

Comment: You implied that you were testing with  "adb shell input keyevent"  rather than custom code.  Do you have an example of that?

Comment: In one terminal window "adb shell input keyevent 32" => 'd' printed on the phone. In another terminal window "adb shell getevent -lt" the output was:

add device 1: /dev/input/event7
  name:     "ffa-keypad"
add device 2: /dev/input/event6
  name:     "ats_input"
add device 3: /dev/input/event5
  name:     "7k_handset"
add device 4: /dev/input/event4
  name:     "proximity"
add device 5: /dev/input/event3
  name:     "bmm050"
add device 6: /dev/input/event2
  name:     "bma2x2"
add device 7: /dev/input/event1
  name:     "vee3_keypad"
add device 8: /dev/input/event0
  name:     "touch_mcs8000"

Comment: I suspect if you locate the effective source of the "input" program (probably there is a trivial wrapper around a launcher for some java code which is what you actually want) you may find that it injects into the downstream android runtime, rather than a kernel input device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like the device i'm working on simply does not have a built-in keyboard, thus no device file on `/dev/input`, so direct injection of text into device file looks like impossible. But `getevent -lit` command said i have following device :

```
add device 2: /dev/input/event6
  bus:      0000
  vendor    0000
  product   0000
  version   0000
  name:     "ats_input"
  location: ""
  id:       ""
  version:  1.0.1
  events:
    KEY (0001): KEY_ESC               KEY_1                 KEY_2                 KEY_3                
                KEY_4                 KEY_5                 KEY_6                 KEY_7                
                KEY_8                 KEY_9                 KEY_0                 KEY_END              
                KEY_VOLUMEDOWN        KEY_VOLUMEUP          KEY_POWER             KEY_SEND             
                KEY_NUMERIC_0         KEY_NUMERIC_1         KEY_NUMERIC_2         KEY_NUMERIC_3        
                KEY_NUMERIC_4         KEY_NUMERIC_5         KEY_NUMERIC_6         KEY_NUMERIC_7        
                KEY_NUMERIC_8         KEY_NUMERIC_9         KEY_NUMERIC_STAR      KEY_NUMERIC_POUND    
    ABS (0003): ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR
```

which is good enough for numbers injection and that is enough for me. 
The `adb shell input keyevent ...` works with virtual keyboard so no device file used (thanks  Chris Stratton )

Comment: @r4jiv007 yes, sure but it only works for injecting number keys, and only on my mobile device.You need to find out which hardware you have o n your mobile. I will share it later, a bit busy now